# Phone number format for EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, input-mask

I am using library [input-mask-android](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android)  to format the text as user is typing.
I have an array of phone number masks. By default, the very first mask in the array is selected. The user can choose a different mask using the Spinner. But when the user selects a mask using the Spinner, it does not work as he would like.
Suppose the array of masks contains two masks: ["+12 - ###", "+34 - ###"]. If the user selects the second mask, then the following will appear when typing into the EditText:
Entered 5 will:
+34-512.
That is, after entering it will automatically put the key characters of the previous mask.
My code in Kotlin:

```
        val listener: MaskedTextChangedListener = installOn(
                etPhoneNumber!!,
                maskT,
                affineFormats, AffinityCalculationStrategy.PREFIX,
                object : ValueListener {
                    override fun onTextChanged(
                            maskFilled: Boolean,
                            extractedValue: String,
                            formattedValue: String
                    ) {
                        logValueListener(maskFilled, extractedValue, formattedValue)
                        Log.e("CHANGE FORMAT:", affineFormats.toString())
                    }
                }
        )
```

maskT - is the selected mask
affineFormats - dynamic array where the last mask is stored.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`input-mask-android` library author here.

The `installOn` method won't suit your needs. You've got to manually [initialise](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/2.-Text-Field-Listener#initialisation) a `MaskedTextChangedListener`, then [call](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/blob/master/inputmask/src/main/kotlin/com/redmadrobot/inputmask/MaskedTextChangedListener.kt#L360) an `addTextChangedListener` method on your `EditText`. On mask select, you've got to make sure the previous listener is removed (by calling a `removeTextChangedListener` on your `EditText`).

The `installOn` method does not consider there could be other `TextWatcher` instances attached to your `EditText`. Thus, all of those installed listeners are trying to take over the text, adding their own "+12" and "+34" prefixes simultaneously.